# sed or perl Remove outer parentheses only if first inner word matches

Tags: regex, perl, bash, sed

Using GNU `sed`, I need to remove parenthetical phrases like `(click here ....)` including the parens.  The text following `click here` varies, but I need to remove the whole outer parentheses.

I've tried many variations on the following, but I can't seem to hit the right one:

```
sed -e 's/\((click here.*[^)]*\)//'
```

**EDIT** Foolishly I didn't notice that there's often actually a linebreak in the middle of the parenthetical string, so `sed` probably isn't going to work.  Example:

```
(click here to
enter some text)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With perl you can run :

```
perl -00 -pe "s/\(click here [^)]*\)//g" inputfile > outputfile
```

It will read the inputfile in a string then replace all occurrences of `(click here anychar but '(' )` then output all in the outputfile.

Comment: @Michael: it defines the record separator as null, so the whole file is read in a single string.

Answer (score 3):

If there aren't nested parens, maybe you can try something like:

```
sed -e 's/(click here [^)]*)//'
```

Comment: This has the result of removing the `click here` and whatever single word immediately follows, leaving the remaining words and the parens.  e.g. `(click here to enter text)` becomes `( enter text)`

Comment: @Michael, probably not. At least it works here. Anyway, I just discovered that you don't need to escape the parens. I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Michael: Can you provide a test case that it doesn't work on?  Consider: `echo "This is a test of the (click here to enter text) system" | sed -e 's/(click here [^)]*)//'`  Note you might want a g after the last / if multiple clicks might appear on a line.

Comment: @Seth Robertson I just found what this doesn't work and facepalmed.  In the file I'm testing this operation on, linebreaks sometimes occur in the middle of the parenthetical string.

Answer (score 1):

Here's yet another `sed` approach that keeps the complete input in the hold buffer:

```
# see http://austinmatzko.com/2008/04/26/sed-multi-line-search-and-replace/
echo '
()
(do not delete this)
()
(click here to
enter some text)
()
' | 
sed -n '1h;1!H;${;g;s/(\([^)]*\))/\1/g;p;}'
```